# How can I preload .mp3 in iOS while playing a song?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio

Is there any ability to preload a song (the next one in the game) while already playing the other one. I want the second song to start immediately after the first one. How can I achieve this effect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a AVQueuePlayer, queue up all the tracks you want. Set the `actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance`

This should then play them with no break. If you still get a break, try creating two separate AVPlayers, and then switch between them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use schedular or timer-NSTimer method to play the song....

Comment: There is more easy way for doing this. I can become a AVAudioPlayer delegate and receive playback termination and start new song here. The problem is that new song must be preloaded at this moment

Comment: Have you tried this...[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]preloadEffect:@"music.wav"];

Comment: I need .mp3. With .wav everything is simple

Comment: yeah you can use .mp3,instead of .wav

Comment: SimpleAudioEngine is using AVAudioPlayer. It is not possible to preload more then one song using it (or i don't know how). I've tried preloading the playing one and next. Then if I send a play message to player it will play last preloaded

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SoundMaster](https://github.com/jerminal/SoundMaster) engine. It's very easy to use, just uses AVAudioPlayer intelligently. It has handy completion block and music preload ability. It can preload multiple files.